# ERROR - images changing are after screen scrolling

Tags: android, json, imageview

I created a JSON Feed Reader in Android. Works. However, thumbnails,  images changing are after screen scrolling.

"Come together to advance"

**Updated code. Inserted the Custom ListAdapter. ->**

```
            public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                private ArrayList<FeedItem> listData;

                private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

                public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> listData) {
                    this.listData = listData;
                    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return listData.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return listData.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    ViewHolder holder;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                        holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                    } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }

                    FeedItem newsItem = (FeedItem) listData.get(position);
                    holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getTitle());
                    holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());

                    if (holder.imageView != null) {
                        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getAttachments());
                    }

                    return convertView;
                }

                static class ViewHolder {
                    TextView headlineView;
                    TextView reportedDateView;
                    ImageView imageView;
                }
            }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

MY FeedListActivity  ->

```
public class FeedListActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<FeedItem> feedList = null;
    private ProgressBar progressbar = null;
    private ListView feedListView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts_list);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        String url = "MY_URL_IN_JSON";
        new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url);



    }


    /*
    public void lol() {  VER SINAL DE INTERNET

     boolean redeOK = AndroidUtil.verificaInternet(this);

     if (redeOK) {
         //AndroidUtil.alertDialog(this, "Conexão encontrada");
         Toast.makeText(this, "Sinal encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } else {
        //AndroidUtil.alertDialog(this, "Conexão não encontrada");
         Toast.makeText(this, "Sinal não encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         finish();
     }

    }*/

    public void updateList() {
        feedListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
        feedListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        feedListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, feedList));
        feedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = feedListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                FeedItem newsData = (FeedItem) o;

                Intent intent = new Intent(FeedListActivity.this, FeedDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("feed", newsData);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

AsyncTask enables you to implement MultiThreading without get Hands dirty into threads. AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. It allows performing background operations and passing the results on the UI thread. If we are doing something isolated related to UI, for example downloading data and prepare for a list, it is recemended to use AsyncTask.

```
    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (null != feedList) {
                Toast.makeText(FeedListActivity.this, R.string.action_settings,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateList();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];

            try {
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = getJSONFromUrl(url);

                //parsing json data
                parseJson(json);
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }


        }
    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String json = null;

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    public void parseJson(JSONObject json) {
        try {

            // parsing json object
            if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");
                JSONArray posts_2 = json.getJSONArray("post_2");


                feedList = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = (JSONObject) posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                    item.setTitle(post.getString("title"));
                    item.setDate(post.getString("date"));
                    item.setId(post.getString("id"));
                    item.setUrl(post.getString("url"));
                    item.setAttachments(post.getString("thumb"));
                    item.setContent(post.getString("content"));
                    item.setAttachmentUrl(post.getString("attachments"));



                    feedList.add(item);

                }


                /*
                for (int i = 0; i < posts_2.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post2 = (JSONObject) posts_2.getJSONObject(i);
                FeedItem item2 = new FeedItem();

                item2.setTitle(post2.getString("title"));
                item2.setDate(post2.getString("date"));
                item2.setId(post2.getString("id"));
                item2.setUrl(post2.getString("url"));
                item2.setAttachments(post2.getString("thumb"));
                item2.setContent(post2.getString("content"));
                item2.setAttachmentUrl(post2.getString("attachments"));
                feedList.add(item2);


                }*/


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**MY CLASS TO DOWNLOAD IMAGE ->**

```
    public class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        // Actual download method, run in the task thread
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {

                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_placeholder));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ViewHolder pattern as suggested by Google: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: How can I implement this in my class Image Downloader Task?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear, add it to your CustomAdapter. The problem lies with the adapter, is a very common problem with listviews.

Comment: Updated code. Inserted the Custom ListAdapter. See.

Comment: What I suggest you should do is set the link as a tag on the ImageView like this: `if(holder.imageView.getTag() == null) {   holder.imageView.setTag(newsItem.getAttachments());             }               newImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(holder.imageView.getTag());`

Comment: You know how put in cach the pictures downloaded? Already i have the codes from another application, but I cannot implement here. I don't know.

Comment: Sorry but that is a whole other case, i suggest you create a new thread for that